# ui sortable object

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'am using the following code:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    cursor: 'move',
    update: function (e, ui) { 
        alert(ui.position);
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

But I don't get the position as expected.

Does `ui` object has position, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It does, ui.position is an object. You need to call ui.position.left and ui.position.top.